# Playing CustomSounds in my SoundBoard app

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

i am currently making a basic SoundBoard App in which i have some hard coated sounds i.e. animals, cartoons etc , i have also added a custom sound option so that the user can record a new sound and save it to play back from the list... Everything works fine but when i save the sound it doesn't playback when i click the play button, otherwise the sound plays before saving... i added following code o distinguish b/w customsounds and already saved sounds playback but it doesn't seem to work for me..

```
if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
{
    AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
else 
{
    using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
    { 
        using(var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open
          ,FileAccess.Read , storageFolder))
        {
            AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

help much appreciated...

Comment: If I had to venture a guess without looking up `IsolatedStorageFileStrem`s I'd say it's because in your `if` statement you're checking if the file exists, and then in your `else` statement you use the file path as an argument. You've already verified the file does NOT exist, how is the stream supposed to open it?

Comment: @Leon Newswanger,  thanks for the comment but in if statement i am checking if the file exists in my assets and in else statement i am referencing an isolated storage in the  phone memory where my custom sound was saved.... don't know what to do, i'm stuck ..

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now. I misunderstood the context in which you were doing this. That being said, are you getting any kind of errors or warnings, or is it simply not playing?

Comment: No error or exception at all, the recorded sound plays when i play it after recording but it doesn't when i save it permanently i.e in phone's isolated storage for the app..

Comment: Okay, kind of a dumb question but, have you tried to access any files in the isolated storage besides the recorded sound files? Also, are you testing this using an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: No, i am only saving the recorded files on the isolated storage, testing it on an emulator..

Comment: Okay, another question, what type is `AudioPlayer` in this example?

Comment: sorry ! i don't understand ...is there multiple types of audioplayer ?

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few ways to play sound with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AudioPlayer.Play();
```

If it doesnt work for you then, you can do it by

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())

{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
         media.SetSource(fileStream);
         media.Play();
    }
}
grid.Children.Add(media);
```